# Point subdomain and root/www to different Heroku apps

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, dnsimple

I've been trying to set up the DNS for a couple of apps using the same domain.

I want www.playfade.com and playfade.com to redirect to playfade.herokuapp.com, so set up a CNAME and ALIAS respectively to point to the Heroku app. This works fine.

I also want beta.playfade.com to point at soundedout.herokuapp.com. To do this, I set up a CNAME for beta.playfade.com to soundedout.herokuapp.com. This, however, doesn't work. When I access beta.playfade.com, I'm redirected to www.playfade.com.

I used MXToolbox to check beta.playfade.com and was given a few errors:

```html
 Bad Glue Detected
Parent server gave glue for beta.playfade.com to be soundedout.herokuapp.com but we resolve that hostname to 176.34.187.173 

 At least one name server failed to respond in a timely manner
Failure detail: 176.34.187.173  

 Local NS list does not match Parent NS list
50.31.242.53 was reported by the parent, but not locally
198.241.11.53 was reported by the parent, but not locally
198.241.10.53 was reported by the parent, but not locally
50.31.243.53 was reported by the parent, but not locally
176.34.187.173 was reported locally, but not by the parent  

 Serial numbers do not match
```

I've set up the domains correctly in the heroku dashboard as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
➜  ~  dig beta.playfade.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> beta.playfade.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 64369
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;beta.playfade.com.     IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
playfade.com.       296 IN  SOA ns1.dnsimple.com. admin.dnsimple.com. 2014110501 86400 7200 604800 300

;; Query time: 668 msec
;; SERVER: 85.37.17.16#53(85.37.17.16)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov  6 10:29:27 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

There is no CNAME configured for the hostname `beta.playfade.com`. Make sure to properly configure it, and make sure you have no redirect configuration inside the app (or if you have it, tweak it accordingly).

Comment: I removed the beta CNAME and added one for 'join' instead. That works fine now, and the beta subdomain still redirects to www. Suppose it's a non-issue now, but strange that it still redirects there.